# What is the easiest way to do XPath querying of XML data in Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, cpan

I am looking for the simplest way possible to quickly retrieve data from an XML structure using XPath queries in Perl.

The following code structure explains what I'd like to achieve:

```
my $xml_data = "<foo><elementName>data_to_retrieve</elementName></foo>";
my $xpath_query = "//elementName";
my $result_of_query = ... what goes here? ...
die unless ($result_of_query eq 'data_to_retrieve');
```

Obviously TIMTOWTDI applies, but what would be the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) is not easier, but beats [XML::XPath](https://metacpan.org/release/XML-XPath) in every other aspect.

```
use XML::LibXML;
my $xml_data = XML::LibXML->load_xml(
    string => '<foo><elementName>data_to_retrieve</elementName></foo>'
);
die unless 'data_to_retrieve' eq
    $xml_data
      ->findnodes('//elementName')
      ->get_node(1)
      ->textContent;
```

Comment: Indeed. It's extremely fast, it has a very clean API, it handles all of XPath, it handles namespaces and everything else you want, etc, etc, etc.

Answer (score 6):

```
use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;

my $xp = XML::XPath->new(xml => $xml_data);

my $result_of_query = $xp->find('//elementName'); # find all nodes that match

foreach my $node ($result_of_query->get_nodelist) {
       #Do someting
}
```

Comment: Yep. XML::XPath is the way to go.

Comment: I wouldn't call XML::XPath the way to go. It is old and not really maintained. XML::LibXML is usually considered a better option see the Perl XML FAQ at http://perl-xml.sourceforge.net/faq/#cpan_modules or the Perl 5 Wiki at http://www.socialtext.net/perl5/recommended_xml_modules