# Can you save to disk using XPath's setNodeText function?

Tags: perl, xpath

I'm using an XPath like "school/student[4]". Could the `setNodeText` function save to harddisk? My changes only seem to be made in memory.

Comment: Which module are you using for xpath queries?

Comment: @Schwern I am using XML::XPath

Comment: XML::XPath hasn't been touched in 10 years, and it doesn't seem to have a documented way of dumping the whole XML structure.  I would suggest using a better maintained XML module as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275610/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-do-xpath-querying-of-xml-data-in-perl

Comment: I agree with @Shwern... Do not use XML::XPath

Comment: @Schwern thanks, is there a way to use the XPath for example("school/student[4]") to traverse the xml tree in other modules, I would hate to have to rewrite everything

Comment: Can you explain more of the problem? There are other things that handle XPath, such as [Mojo::DOM](https://www.metacpan.org/modules/Mojo::DOM).

Comment: Yes, [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::LibXML::Parser) supports XPaths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to change a document then write it to disk.

```
use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc    = $parser->parse_fh(...);
my $root   = $doc->documentElement();

for my $node ($root->findnodes('//school/student[4]')) {
   $node->removeChildNodes();
   $node->appendText("New text");
}

open(my $fh, '>:raw', ...) or die $!;
print($fh $doc->toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dump the XML structure using the undocumented method `getNodeAsXML`. The output isn't garanteed to be valid XML (e.g. no header), but it usually does the trick.

```
my $str = $xp->getNodeAsXML();
print $str;
```

Source: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=567212