# Using XPath with Perl

Tags: perl, xpath

I am trying to replicate what my `C#`/`XPath` code does on Linux using Perl. I copied and pasted the code in Example 8-6 in [Perl & XML](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596002053). If I understand right, I should be able to run that Perl code, put this code in terminal

```
xmlPerl.pl mydatafile.xml "/inventory/category/item/name"
```

But when I try to run the Perl file, it doesn't work. Here is the error:

```
[root@Perl ~]# perl xmlPerl.pl
Can't locate XML/XPath.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.7/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.6/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.7 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.6 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.7/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.6/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.7 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.6 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at xmlPerl.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at xmlPerl.pl line 3.
```

What am I doing wrong? I think it has something to do with the XML and XPath names in the beginning of my code. Do I need to install something to use the XPath framework? I am running on RedHat 5.5.

Comment: From the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [What's the easiest way to install a missing Perl module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865/whats-the-easiest-way-to-install-a-missing-perl-module)

Comment: Try to get a modern book that teaches [LibXML](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) instead, see [What is the easiest way to do XPath querying of XML data in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275610/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-do-xpath-querying-of-xml-data-in-perl)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [`perldiag`](http://metacpan.org/module/perldiag):

> Can't locate %s
>
> You said to do (or require, or use) a file that couldn't be found. Perl looks for the file in all the locations mentioned in `@INC`, unless the file name included the full path to the file. Perhaps you need to set the `PERL5LIB` or `PERL5OPT` environment variable to say where the extra library is, or maybe the script needs to add the library name to `@INC`. Or maybe you just misspelled the name of the file. See `require` in `perlfunc` and `lib`.

You don't have installed `XML::XPath` module, or Perl not found it. Install module with CPAN:

```
> cpan XML::XPath
```

or with package manager:

```
> apt-get install libxml-xpath-perl
```

Or if it already installed say where it is with `PERL5LIB` environment variable:

```
> PERL5LIB=/path/to/lib perl ...
```

`@INC` variable:

```
BEGIN {
    unshift(@INC, '/path/to/lib');
}
```

or `lib` pragma:

```
use lib '/path/to/lib';
```

Comment: That worked, it installed and everything, but now I am getting this error - "No path to find at /usr/lib/per5/site_perl/5.8.8/XML/XPath.pm line 65" I also installed it using cpan.

Answer (score 3):

That's the standard error that comes from trying to `use` a module that isn't installed. You should install it.

Ideally use the OS package for it; for example on a debian-derived OS (such as Debian or Ubuntu)

```
$ apt-get install libxml-xpath-perl
```

Failing that, you can install it as usual using CPAN

```
$ cpan XML::XPath
```

Comment: Ah I see. I am running it on RedHat 5.5 I will try and see if I can find an install for it. I will post back on  it that solution worked! Thank you!

Comment: That worked, it installed and everything, but now I am getting this error - "No path to find at /usr/lib/per5/site_perl/5.8.8/XML/XPath.pm line 65" I also installed it using cpan.

Comment: Well, the `No path to find` error is most likely an actual XPath error, complaining that it can't find the requested node in your data structure. That doesn't sound like a perl error.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the first part of your error:

```
Can't locate XML/XPath.pm
```

In Perl, the huge benefit is from using modules, or libraries, that others have written for you and you can reuse.  In this case, someone has written a module called XML::XPath (in Perl, the path is delineated by '::') and you just need to install it.  The easiest way to install it is via `cpan`, it's a tool that comes installed with most Perl installations.  Just run:

```
cpan
(you'll be dropped into a different command prompt)
install XML::XPath
```

This will go out and fetch XML::XPath, unpack it, generate the Makefile, check for dependencies (and install any that are missing), make it, test it, and install it for you.  Look [here](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html) for more information on using CPAN.

Comment: That worked, it installed and everything, but now I am getting this error - "No path to find at /usr/lib/per5/site_perl/5.8.8/XML/XPath.pm line 65" I also installed it using cpan.