# How to use XPath.pm in perl script?

Tags: perl, xpath

I've followed following link for the issues i faced.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192967/using-xpath-with-perl
```

Really I don't know how to use. Please guide me in proper way.

**Issue :**

```
    Can't locate XML/XPathEngine.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /perl/site/lib C:/Dwimpe
rl/perl/site/lib C:/Dwimperl/perl/vendor/lib C:/Dwimperl/perl/lib .) at C:/Dwimp
erl/perl/site/lib/XPath.pm line 103.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/XPath.pm line 103
.
Compilation failed in require at Multi_instance_run1.pl line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Multi_instance_run1.pl line 9.
```

**The following steps i followed for this**

```
 - In perl script, used like require XPath;
 - After that executed command cpan XML::XPath .
 -I've copied following files in the path C:\Dwimperl\perl\site\lib
              XPath.pm
              XPathEngine.pm
```

what did I miss ? where did I made mistake ? How to use XPath.pm ? How to include it in perl script ?

Comment: Use the `cpan` command instead of copying files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put XPathEngine to C:\Dwimperl\perl\site\lib\XML folder